# Existence of mixed derivatives of C1 function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let f be a real and C1 function of two variables. Is it true that the mixed derivatives exist even if they do not commute?

Comment: Start with one variable. What happens with $f(x) = x|x|$?

Comment: Thank you Ted! I have understood how one can do.